# Use flashlight while barcode scanning on WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, zxing

I want to develop a simple barcode scanner for Windows Phone by using the [zxing barcode sdk](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net/). Now I want to enable flash light. So I'm setting the FlashMode of the camera device to on, but now the light will be turned on while auto focus and will be turned off if auto focus is finished. I've tried to register the auto focus completed event to call the focus method.

So how is it possible to enable flash light without going on and off while scanning a barcode. Thanks.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: You should put your code in your question and try to cut it down to only the code relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The following line works for me:

```
PhotoCaptureDevice.SetProperty(
    KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchMode,
    VideoTorchMode.On);
```